# latex tabular issue

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking

I am creating a `tabular` in LaTeX.

I want one column to be as small as possible, with no inter column spacing, so that it's just enough to fit the text. I know the answer to this question: I need to use `@{}c@{}`.

I also want to be able to have a linebreak wherever I want in my cell. I also know the answer to this question: I need to use a `tabular` within my `tabular`.

The problem is that I can't manage to make these two solutions work together: when I try to have 2 lines within a cell, the column gets expanded beyond the size of the text.

Here is such an example:

```
\begin{small}
        \begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
            A\\B\\C\\   
        \end{tabular}
\end{small}
```

Compare with (in the following code, there is unwanted extra space) :

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
\begin{small}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            A\\B\\C\\   
        \end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that `small` is a macro: `\small` not an environment (however, it also works without error). You might simply have some unwanted spaces, try putting `%` after the `}`  at the end of the source lines.

Comment: There *are* two extra spaces: one after `\begin{small}` and the second after `\end{tabular}`. Saying only `\small` (and removing `\end{small}`) will solve the issue, as Gonzalo says.

Comment: You guys are all right, thank you very much. I don't understand though why adding '%' at the line of the lines solve the issue, I don't see where there are the 'two extra spaces' you mention ?

Comment: @bob a line break is taken as a blank space. Anyway, it's better not to use the font switches as environments.

Comment: Oh okay. I'd like to thank you all and +1 but it says 'please login or register to vote for this post'. I am logged in though, otherwise I wouldn't be able to post here...

Comment: @bob you need still more reputation to upvote; you can [accept answers](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954), though.

Comment: oh okay the error message is just wrong then.

Comment: So just to be sure, what this all means is that I can't actually go to the next line for clarity in my code, since breaking into a new line actually has a special meaning in latex ? This is something I didn't know.

Comment: @bob you can change lines in your code but need to use `%` to prevent the spurious blank spaces. I'll add some remarks to my answer showing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, there are two spurious blank spaces: one, after `\begin{small}`, and the second one, after the inner `\end{tabular}`; you can remove those spaces using `%` at the end of the line. Compare the result obtained in the following example showing your code and a version with the spaces removed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent Undesired blank spaces:
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
\begin{small}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            A\\B\\C\\   
        \end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{tabular}

\noindent Spurious spaces removed: 
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
\begin{small}%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
            A\\B\\C\\   
        \end{tabular}%
\end{small}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\small` is a switch not an environment; use this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   A\\B\\C\\   
   \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

With this input, spurious spaces don't show up because `tabular` ignores white space at the start and end of cells (and the endline after `\small` is ignored because it's a command name).

When nesting `tabular`s normally is convenient to enclose the inner one using braces; in this case, however it's not necessary since the inner `tabular` only has one column.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
  \small
  \begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|}
    A\\B\\C
  \end{tabular}&
  Some more text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the vertical rules is placed in the innermost `tabular` where you use your line breaks. You could also consider the [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) which does something similar. Here's a short example that produces similar output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|l}
  \small
  \makecell{A\\B\\C}&
  Some more text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```